# High disk I/O from calaccessd

Tags: macos, calendar

I am running macOS Ventura (13.5) on an iMac with a Fusion Drive and was noticing that the system felt more and more sluggish over the past months. I also heard the hard drive work all the time. There are [many reasons why Fusion Drives are no longer a recommended setup](https://bombich.com/de/blog/2019/09/12/analysis-apfs-enumeration-performance-on-rotational-hard-drives), so I initially dismissed this as an inefficiency of the aging Fusion Drive setup I had.

A disk I/O monitor (I used iStatMenus) shows some continued background activity by `calaccessd`, just a few hundred kB/s however.

Is that normal behaviour for `calaccessd`?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of analysis, it turned out this was not normal behaviour and actually the source of many performance problems.

I checked what files `calaccessd` maintains, and found that the main calendar database is located in `~/Library/Calendars/Calendar.sqlitedb`. For unknown reasons, this file had grown to over 3.5 GB, and the WAL log right next to it was at an astonishing 2.5 GB, which was obviously abnormal and far outside the recommended range for a SQLite database.

My mistake in diagnosing this was to check the disk throughput. That was indeed very low, a few hundred kB/s, and would not have impacted the system much. But there were lots of discrete I/O *events*.

I remedied the issue by deactivating all calendar sources in the settings panel of the Calendar app. After shutting Calendar down, I moved the entire old Calendar folder into a backup location. I then started Calendar again, added the calendar sources again and the application transparently recreated the ~/Library/Calendar folder.

My system is now noticeably more responsive overall, and disk activity actually drops to 0 kB/s r/w and 0 events during idle times, which it never really did before.